# Row in dataframe to matrix (for proximity ratings)

Tags: r, matrix, row, reshape

A number of participants (p1, p2, ...) gave proximity ratings for all pairwise combinations of 4 words (w1.w2, w1.w3, ..., w3.w4), giving the following dataframe:

```
id  w1.w2  w1.w3  w1.w4  w2.w3  w2.w4  w3.w4  
p1      3      1      6      3      5      2
p2      2      3      5      1      6      1
p3 .....
```

I would like to convert these ratings into a series of matrices to apply multidimensional scaling to them (1 matrix by participant).
I would like to convert my data to the following format:

```
id  first.wd.in.pair  w2  w3  w4  
p1                w1   3   1   6  
p1                w2       3   5  
p1                w3           2
p2                w1   2   3   5  
p2                w2       1   6  
p2                w3           1  
p3 .....
```

I've looked into all kinds of reformatting options (e.g. `cast` in `reshape2`), but nothing seems to fit my issue.
I've also looked at functions for adjacency matrix (such as `get.adjacency()` in `igraph`, but from what I saw it seemed to require something in the following format:

```
id    first.word   second.word   rating
p1            w1            w2        3  
p1            w1            w3        1  
p1            w1            w4        6  
p1  ....
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You've looked into reformatting options? I don't believe you! Show us your code!!! Pretty please. And what actually you would like as output. Welcome to SO :-)

Comment: I apologize for not showing the code for my attempts. This was my first question on Stack Overflow (and I'm relatively new to R) and I'll make sure to post a question that includes it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach is `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2".

I don't know what you tried, but it is pretty standard-procedure except for one step: splitting the molten "variable" column. Assuming your input `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
dfL <- melt(mydf, id.vars="id")
dfL <- cbind(dfL, colsplit(dfL$variable, "\\.", c("first", "other")))
dcast(dfL, id + first ~ other, value.var="value", fill=0)
#   id first w2 w3 w4
# 1 p1    w1  3  1  6
# 2 p1    w2  0  3  5
# 3 p1    w3  0  0  2
# 4 p2    w1  2  3  5
# 5 p2    w2  0  1  6
# 6 p2    w3  0  0  1
```

---

Here, "mydf" is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c("p1", "p2"), w1.w2 = c(3L, 2L), w1.w3 = c(1L, 
    3L), w1.w4 = c(6L, 5L), w2.w3 = c(3L, 1L), w2.w4 = 5:6, w3.w4 = c(2L, 
    1L)), .Names = c("id", "w1.w2", "w1.w3", "w1.w4", "w2.w3", "w2.w4", 
    "w3.w4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Please share your sample data in such a format in the future.

Comment: I was stuck after the `melt` step, so the column splitting step you described really solved my issue. The best I had been able to accomplish was to go from wide to long form by using `reshape` in `reshape`, which isn't what I need. I wasn't able to use `dcast` effectively, so this is perfect, many thanks.